shell-expand-line and shebangs
In bash, the very useful shell-expand-line (M-C-e) expands command substitutions to their contents, on the current line. However, this works very strangely for commands without shebangs.
One may verify this by the following.

Create a simple executable file with and without shebang.

echo echo hi >> test-no-shebang
chmod +x test-no-shebang
echo '#!/bin/sh' >> test-shebang
echo echo hi >> test-shebang
chmod +x test-shebang


Enter `./test-shebang`, then M-C-e. This works as expected, expanding the line to hi. C-_ works normally, undoing the expansion.
Enter `./test-no-shebang`, then M-C-e. This works strangely, indeed expanding the line to hi, but removing the prompt in front of the line. C-_ does not work, printing the character literally instead, and nor do most bindings, but C-u kind of works, successfully clearing the line (but not clearing the hi).

Why is this the case? Can I make shell-expand-line work for scripts without shebang?
EDIT:

Some comments thought that it would be wise for me to mention that the mentioned key-bindings refer to the emacs line-editing bindings (which are the default bash key-bindings).

With more testing, I observe that I can reproduce the problem on the mac Terminal and on kitty on bash version 5.2.15(1)-release, but cannot reproduce the problem on bash 3.2.57(1)-release.



What does M-C-e mean? How would I invoke that?

@pfnuesel M-C-e refers to Meta-Control-e. The typical setting for Meta is the alt key, so you can try invoking Alt-Control-e. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Introduction-and-Notation for more information.

Cannot reproduce but you should always use a shebang on all scripts.

The default assumption by readers of your question will not be that you're using set -o emacs (EMACS mode command-line editing), so I suggest mentioning that explicitly in your question.

@SottoVoce I can add it to the question, but it would be strange to me that anyone would assume that I'm not using emacs line-editing, since its the default.

@user22476690 in my experience with Ubuntu since 8.04 and CentOS 6x and 7.x, the Bash default is no command-line editing at all.  And the confusion expressed in previous comments about the meaning of the Emacs keystroke references ("M-C-e") is one small bit of additional evidence to indicate questions involving the editing modes are unusual here.

@SottoVoce It seems to me that some systems set up their shells as non-interactive. This is a strange and painful setup, since non-interactive mode lacks all the ergonomic features for interactive use. You might find this helpful if you wanted to make your shell interactive https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html

I suggest reporting this as a bug to the appropriate mailing list. The only two things different between the listed versions of Bash in the function shell_expand_line from the file bashline.c are 1. the new function expand_string_dollar_quote is called from shell_expand_line, 2. the function expand_word is used in 5.2.32 instead of the code calling expand_string in 3.2.57, which is retained in the file but commented out. My guess is there is some kind of unwanted interaction of new functions with Readline.

@Vilinkameni Thanks for your information and suggestions, let me report this.

Gratitude to @Vilinkameni for proposing to consult the mailing list; the wizards of GNU swiftly offered a diagnosis of this issue as a known bug, already fixed in the devel branch. Presumably, this will be fixed for versions above 5.2.
